# Arch Linux: Building wireshark-git error (syntax error?)

Tags: python, linux, makefile, wireshark, archlinux

I using ArchLinux 64-bit with both python2 and python3 installed.

I am trying to build [wireshark-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wireshark-git/) as per the [linked instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_packages).

I have tried manually building the package, and using yaourt as well. Additionally I have tried changing the PKGBUILD as per a suggestion on the package's comment page as well:

```
Change:

"/usr/lib/python2.7/Tools/scripts/reindent.py $srcdir/$_svnmod/tools/ncp2222.py"

to:

/usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/Tools/scripts/reindent.py </code>
```

I am able to "makepkg" then "./configure --with-ssl". However, as soon as I try to run the final "make" to build an installable file, I always get this error:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/builds/wireshark-git/src/wireshark/packaging'
Making all in help
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/builds/wireshark-git/src/wireshark/help'
  GEN      faq.txt
  File "./../tools/html2text.py", line 332
    self.o("][" + `a['count']` + "]")
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Makefile:684: recipe for target 'faq.txt' failed
make[2]: *** [faq.txt] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/builds/wireshark-git/src/wireshark/help'
Makefile:3458: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/builds/wireshark-git/src/wireshark'
Makefile:2058: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do have wireshark-gtk installed as well. Base-devel in installed, as is libsmi. So it seems like the error has to do with python, specifically the "**html2text.py**". I believe it is not yet compatible with python 3, so I did try forcing it to use python2 by uncommenting and editing the first line to be "*#!/usr/bin/env python2*", still no dice. I can post any additional output that is needed.

Comment: Is that still valid question?

Comment: It actually is, but I have submitted a bug report.  Should this be closed now?

Comment: Did you try reproducing it lately? I tried and building wireshark-git fails for me but from different reason `configure: error: Lua support was requested, but is not available`